# How do i store a table with constants and cache it in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table with constants that i would like to load on startup so my classes have access to it. In addition, I would like it to refresh after about an hour if somebody hits the webapp (1 hr. cache)

I am guessing that I should put this in the initialize with a Rails.cache around it but I'm not sure when other methods from the controller would call it after initialization.

Any recommendations on my approach?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using a read-through caching mechanism for this. If you're referring to a table mapped to an ActiveRecord model, checkout out shopify's [identity_cache](https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache) for a recent implementation of this idea relevant to Rails 3.